# Synonym for "controls" meaning switches and buttons etc

Tags: synonyms

Talking about a control panel with multiple switches, dials, knobs, lights and buttons, I am looking for a synonym for "controls" (and the singular "control").  I have "instrument panel" or "dashboard" as synonyms for "control panel", but nothing else that exactly seems to cover the collection itself.

"Instruments" is the closest I can find, but to me that implies larger items such as a speedometer that can include multiple dials and buttons, rather than just the buttons or switches themselves.  So it works in the second example, less well in the first and not in the third.

Example uses:

"All the "x" on the dashboard had been set to their emergency positions"

"George swept his hand over the "x" rapidly preparing for liftoff."

"This "x" was a three-way switch instead of the usual button."

Comment: The only two synonyms the OED offers for that sense of "control" are "regulator" and "instrument".

Comment: Why do you need a synonym? What is it about *controls* that doesn't work? Without more explanation, *controls* seems like the best choice in all of your examples . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford When describing the systems behind some "control panels" there is a need to talk about "logic controllers" and "control loops" so it would be useful to have a more distinguishable word for the "controls".  And when I couldn't find one I was curious enough to ask here to see if it really was the only precise word for it.

Comment: Okay, but that's unrelated to the example sentences you gave. What you just described is more like system processes that aren't visible—software that's running on the hardware. I can't see anybody confusing the two. In fact, you can use the term *control software* to distinguish that from the *controls*.

Comment: Ah. Unless you're already talking about *logic controllers* specifically and fear that mentioning just *controls* immediately before or after could be confusing. Any rephrasing would need to be contextual: *this switch was up*,*that button was depressed*, *the flight computer was set to manual*, and so on. If you don't mind repeating the word *control* as part of a phrase, you could say the *control element*, *control device*, or *interactive control*.

Comment: "All of the ***dashboard*** *controls* had been set to their emergency positions." "This *control* ***element*** was a three-way switch instead of the usual button." If you feel those are still inappropriate, you'll have to provide more context—the sentences used alongside other sentences that would make their use awkward.

Comment: I tried to make the question more general so it would be useful to other people and so they would more clearly understand the examples, as by that point I was resigned to some version of "control" (as you listed) for my required use, but was just hoping someone might still have another suggestion.

Comment: I prefer to use "knobby thingies".

Comment: I like the suggestion of 'knobby thingies' by @HotLicks but seriously you could use 'manual controls' for all the switches, buttons, knobs or even proximity sensors on the control panel. I wouldn't use 'instruments' as, to me, that means display elements such as dials and digital diplays rather than controls where settings can be changed in reponse to the displayed information. It is possible for a piece of equipment to have a control panel with switches, knobs etc and a separate instrument panel with status displays.

Comment: @BoldBen - Yeah, certainly to an Apollo era techie "instruments" refers to devices whose primary purpose is to present information to the user.

Comment: @HotLicks Absolutely, unless you're talking about guitars violins and things....

Answer (score 1):

*[Interface](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interface)* is the common term for such a collection of controls and displays.

> **interface**, *n.*: A device or program for connecting two [or more] items of hardware or software so that they can be operated jointly or
>   communicate with each other.

For your examples:

> All *interfaces* on the dashboard had been set to their emergency
>   positions.
>
> George swept his hand over the *interface*, rapidly preparing for
>   liftoff.
>
> This *interface* was a three-way switch instead of the usual button.

Comment: I think of "interface" primarily with regards to computer software, and "user interface" is usually the collection of items used for control more akin to the "control panel" or "dashboard".  What would you call an individual element on the Interface?

Comment: Note that the Oxford Dictionaries definition quoted says "a device... for connecting... items of hardware _or_ software." An individual knob, switch, or slider on an interface is still a _control_; in most UI toolkits, such elements are usually referred to as _widgets_, however.